# rename remote git branch when file name is too long

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have a remote branch (hosted in bitbucket) that displays a git error saying file name too long.

error: unable to resolve reference that_really_long_branch_name: File name too long

When I try to check it out to rename it I get a message similar to:

error: pathspec 'that_really_long_branch_name' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Does anyone know of a way to rename it within bitbucket or thru git?

Comment: What is your operating system and the file system. Likely it's restrictions of the platform.

Comment: I'm in linux, but could also access via windows

Comment: Ohh, /usually/ unix filesystems are less restrictive than windows filesystem, so unlikely switching the OS would help. What is FS in Linux, ext4?

Comment: Unless you think it would "out" you, post the real full path (pwd output) of the local directory you're in, the actual git command, the output of the command, and the full path of the local .git directory.  Also, git status wouldn't hurt either.